# Extract latitude/longitude from an image using curl

Tags: jpeg, exif

`curl -s -v -X HEAD http://sitename.com/123.jpg 2>&1 | grep '^< Last-Modified:'` gets me a date. Any way I can retrieve gps coordinates of an image? Any other metadata?

Comment: This is not a `curl` question but a `jpeg`-parsing one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you are getting there is not the time at which the photo was taken. It is the time at which the `123.jpg` file was last modified (or created/uploaded onto the server). That information comes from the web server, which gets it from the file's timestamps. The photo could very well be 10 years older than what you get. Actually, it wouldn't be too difficult to make it look like it comes from the future!

The information you're looking for is (optionally) stored into the image's metadata. From a webserver's perspective, that's part of the file's actual content, which means an HTTP `HEAD` request will not be enough. First, you need to download the file. Let's use [that picture of a boat](https://exposingtheinvisible.org/ckeditor_assets/pictures/32/content_example_ibiza.jpg) as an example.

If you run your `curl` command, you'll see that the file was last modified on the 13th of October 2015. Once you've downloaded the file, this date will also appear in the file's timestamps (provided you preserve them accross downloads, which I believe `wget` does).

Now once you've got the file, all you need to do is access its metadata.  On Linux, I'd say `identify` and `exiftool` are the most popular choices for that. In your case:

```
$ identify -format "%[EXIF:*GPS*]" image.jpg
$ exiftool -gpslatitude -gpslongitude image.jpg
```

Note that you don't really have to download the contents into an actual file in order to run these checks. You could easily use a pipe:

```
$ curl http://example.com/image.jpg | identify -format "%[EXIF:*GPS*]" -
$ curl http://example.com/image.jpg | exiftool -gpslatitude -gpslongitude -
```

**An important note though:** geotagging is not a systematic process. Not all images have GPS coordinates embedded in them. If the device used to take the picture is GPS-enabled and actually writes GPS metadata, then you're good (smartphones can do that...). Otherwise, these two commands will not return anything, in which case you'll have to be [more creative](https://xkcd.com/1425/) to determine the location...

Comment: Running `exiftool` directly on the `jpg` ... file  is more efficient

Comment: "in which case you'll have to be more creative to determine the location..." - post it to travel.SE and say you want to visit the location in the picture